# Write a sql query to return movie with two ratings?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this

columns names

> mid,rating
>
> M1 R1
>
> M1 R2
>
> M2 R3
>
> M3 R4

I want to return movies with two ratings exact(this is a mini problem of the problem I am solving)

Expected result is mid and its ratings.

> select * from movie
>
> where 2 = (select count(*) from movie b group by b.mid and b.mid=mid )

This is not working as expected,I dont even have any idea what it is doing. Can anyone explain to me what can I do to get the expected result.

> **I Can't use having, I have to compare 'result of a subquery' with 2.**

Comment: The real Batman would know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use `HAVING`, then you can use something like this:

```
select *
from movie m1
where 2 = (select count(*)
           from movie m2
           where m1.mid = m2.mid)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e6628/3)

If you want to return those with a distinct rating count, then you can use:

```
select *
from movie m1
where 2 = (select count(distinct rating)
           from movie m2
           where m1.mid = m2.mid)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e6628/5)

Comment: @Batman did you see the demo it is a sqlite demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e6628/1 . What version are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet: You can skip the `GROUP BY` :)

Comment: @ypercube well look at that, I learned something today. thx and updated

Comment: @bluefeet column name duplication duh :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT mid
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY mid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**UPDATE**

Well, if you can't use `HAVING` (why?), then you can try a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM movie A
INNER JOIN (SELECT mid, COUNT(*) ratings
            FROM movie
            GROUP BY mid) B
    ON A.mid = B.mid
WHERE 2 = B.ratings
```

Comment: Cant use having, I have to compare 'result of subquery' with 2.

Comment: Join the result of this back to your 'movie' table to get the ratings, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Using your original query:

```
select * from 
mid a where 
(
    (select count(*) 
       from mid b 
      where b.mid = a.mid 
      group by b.mid) = 2
);
```

just added an alias for the outer table and parentheses for the subquery comparison to 2.

```
Results:
mid     rating
m1      r1
m1      r2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT `mid`, count(rating) AS `rating_count`
FROM table
WHERE `rating_count` = 2
GROUP BY `mid`
```

Here you simply count the number of occurrences of `rating` for each group of `mid`. You then filter on that value (which is stored in `rating_count` here).

Comment: Can you please explain this? this is the first time I am seeing a query like this.

Comment: I'm not too versed on SQLite, but this will work without a `GROUP BY` and using the column alias on the `WHERE`?

Comment: Is there any way I can compare the result of a subquery with a constant number?

Comment: Sorry I h left out my GROUP BY clause when typicing this.  I have added explanation as well.

Comment: @MikeBrant Ok, there is the `GROUP BY` now, but your `WHERE` should be a `HAVING`, and (strangely) op can't use `HAVING`

Comment: This is not valid SQL, @Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines if you want to show actual ratings

```
SELECT mid, rating FROM movie m
JOIN (SELECT mid, COUNT(*) FROM movie GROUP BY mid HAVING COUNT(*)=2) c 
ON (m.mid = c.mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` can and should be used; I tested with SQLite 2.8.17 & 3.6.22.

To get the movies with two ratings:

```
SELECT mid
FROM movie
GROUP BY mid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

You can then use that in an `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM movie
WHERE mid in (
    SELECT mid
    FROM movie
    GROUP BY mid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
);
```

or join it back:

```
SELECT movie.*
FROM movie
    JOIN (
        SELECT mid
        FROM movie
        GROUP BY mid
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    ) those_with_two
        ON movie.mid = those_with_two.mid;
```

Full test case set-up, for reference:

```
$ sqlite3 so-movie

create table movie (
    mid varchar(10),
    rating varchar(10)
);

insert into movie values('M1','R1');
insert into movie values('M1','R2');
insert into movie values('M2','R3');
insert into movie values('M3','R4');
```

I say `HAVING` should be used for a few reasons:

1. it's more flexible if you want more than one clause, e.g. movies with two ratings or where mid='M3'
2. it will perform better than Lamak's second solution (the explain plan shows that hitting three tables)
3. it's easier to read and understand